# Multi-routes to component with exact in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I have a component which should be shown when you first load the webpage but also on a specific route.

So, I have the component Users and this one should be shown in 2 cases: "/" or "/users".

Currently I do it like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Users} />
    <Route path="/users" exact component={Users} />
</Switch>
```

There are also other routes in the Switch, however not necessary to copy.
I know it is possible to do multi routing:

```
<Route path={"/" | "/users"} component={Users} />
```

However this does not work because I cannot use exact. How can I achieve it in this way?

Comment: "I cannot use exact", why ?

Comment: @MB_ Because it doesn't work, just adding exact does not switch between the routes, it always matches "/"

Comment: try my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Redirect

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Result :

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/users" component={Users} />

 <Route exact path="/">
  <Redirect to="/users" />
 </Route>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey I tried it out and found a solution.

```js
const [x, setX] = useState(false)

<Route path={x ? "/profile" : "/other"} component={Users} />
```

then if you click a link that should get you to /profile add onClick={() => setX(true)}
and if /other add to onClick={() => setX(false)}